# Is JFrog Cli the best available option to use for a Jenkins CI server?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory, jfrog-cli

I have been using artifactory plugin with jenkins for a while now.

And I have come across the [JFrog CLI](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/JFrog+CLI) and it says:

> *simplifying your automation scripts and making them more readable and easier to maintain*

So is it high time for me to use [JFrog CLI](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/JFrog+CLI) or stick with the [Jenkins Artifactory Plug-in](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Jenkins+Artifactory+Plug-in)?

Any thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

[Jfrog CLI](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/JFrog+CLI) help a lot if you have a script as pipeline.

For example, a Bamboo sh script or a Jenkins pipeline in Groovy.

If you are using the [Jenkins Artifactory plugin](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Jenkins+Artifactory+Plug-in) for Jenkins and don't need any extra feature I don't recommend you to change your method.

[Jfrog CLI](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/JFrog+CLI) help a lot but is more easy to use the [Jenkins Artifactory plug-in](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Jenkins+Artifactory+Plug-in).

Comment: So artifactory plugin is the way. Have I understood that correct ?

Comment: Yes, for you user case is the best option.